# Converting enum values to strings in C++

Tags: c++, enum

Question 1: functionxxx_as_string() is used below.  How else could it be more elegantly named?

Question 2: Is the static char* array method adopted below the only solution?  Best solution?  Any suggestions?

Generally, I have this issue where my list of enums will be from 3 - say 50 items, mostly less than 20 items and they are fairly static.

```
   #include <iostream>

   enum thing_type
   {
      DTypeAnimal,
      DTypeMineral,
      DTypeVegetable,
      DTypeUnknown
   };

   class thing {
   public:
      thing(thing_type type) : type_(type) {}
      const thing_type get_state() const { return type_; }
      const char* get_state_as_string() const {
         static const char* ttype[] = { 
               "Animal",
               "Mineral",
               "Vegetable",
               "Unknown" 
         };
         return ttype[type_];   
      }

   private:
      thing_type type_;
   };


   int main() {
      thing th(DTypeMineral);
      std::cout << "this thing is a " << th.get_state_as_string() << std::endl;

      return 0;
   }
```

I am preferring to remove all the printing stuff from the class interface and use the operator<< overloading idea in 200_success answer like this:

```
#include <iostream>

enum thing_type
{
   DTypeUnknown,
   DTypeAnimal,
   DTypeMineral,
   DTypeVegetable
};

const char* type2string(thing_type ttype) {
   static const char* thtype[] = { 
      "Unknown",
      "Animal",
      "Mineral",
      "Vegetable"
   };
   return ttype < sizeof(thtype) ? thtype[ttype] : thtype[0];   
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const thing_type type) {
   os << type2string(type);
   return os;
}

class thing {
public:
   thing(thing_type type) : type_(type) {}
   const thing_type get_type() const { return type_; }

private:
   thing_type type_;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const thing& th) {
   os << "This is a " << type2string(th.get_type());
   return os;
}

int main() {
   thing th(DTypeMineral);
   std::cout << th << std::endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: In general, the values of an enum are not required to be unique, e.g. `enum light { red, yellow, green, stop = 0, go = 2 };`. That makes the name for a given value plural.

Comment: I find the way .net has it is awesome - xxxxToString? (But I'm biased :)

Comment: Also see: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/14315/507

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Question 1: functionxxx_as_string() is used below. How else could it be more elegantly named?

How about:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& str, thing const& data);
```

> Question 2: Is the static char* array method adopted below the only solution? Best solution? Any suggestions?

You will need a static char array (or equivalent (like a switch)) somewhere as there is no built in way to convert enum values (which are integers) to a string.

Comment: I feel a bit bad about changing my mind but only just seen byour answer.  Agree overloading operator<< is better approach.  See my update above.

Answer (score 1):

You should use one of the preprocessor macro-based solutions proposed in [StackOverflow Question 147267](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147267). For example, here is a solution using X() macros. I've also rewritten your `get_state_as_string()` as a stringifier for iostream.

```
#include <iostream>

#define X_THINGS \
  X(DTypeAnimal,    "Animal") \
  X(DTypeMineral,   "Mineral") \
  X(DTypeVegetable, "Vegetable") \
  X(DTypeUnknown,   "Unknown")

typedef enum {
#   define X(Enum, String) Enum,
    X_THINGS
#   undef X
} thing_type;

class Thing {
  public:
    Thing(thing_type type) : type_(type) {}
    const thing_type get_state() const { return type_; }
    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream&, const Thing&);

  private:
    thing_type type_;
};

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Thing &t) {
    switch (t.get_state()) {
#   define X(Enum, String) \
      case Enum: os << String; break;
      X_THINGS
#   undef X
    }
    return os;
}

int main() {
   Thing th(DTypeMineral);
   std::cout << "this thing is a " << th << std::endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'd paste at least one of the examples here to make this answer more valuable.

Comment: Yes I don't like all the as_string functions.  I prefer overloading operator<< - and taking the printing stuff out of the class.

Comment: Since this is C++ proposing a C solution is probably not a good idea. The same affective can be done much better using language features in C++.

Answer (score 1):

//I lost original answer I wanted to post on stackoverflow...

> Question 1: functionxxx_as_string() is used below. How else could it be more elegantly named?

```
 const char *to_string(thing_type type);
```

It doesn't have to be class member.

> Question 2: Is the static char* array method adopted below the only solution? Best solution? Any suggestions?

Not the only solution, may or may not be the best solution.

Potential problems - if your enum has "holes" `enum Asdf{a = 1, b = 48, c}`, array of names won't work.

You'll need to use array of pairs, std::map or plain old switch/case.

//warning: I haven't compiled the code, there might be typos.

array of pairs:

```
const char *tOstring(thing_type type){
    struct Data{
         thing_type type;
         const char *name;
    };

    static const Data data[] = {
         {thing, "thing"},
         ....
         {unusued_value, 0)
    };

    //if you use binary search here, it'll be faster
    for (const Data* cur = data[]; data->name; data++){
        if (cur->type == type)
            return cur->name;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

std::map:

```
typedef std::map<thing_type, std::string> NameMap;
NameMap nameMap;//somewhere
std::string toString(thing_type type){
     NameMap::const_iterator found = nameMap.find(type);
     if (found == nameMap.end())
           return std::string; //or throw exception
     return found.second;
}
```

You can make array of pairs static const, but std::map will need to be initialized somewhere. However, with std::map you can add/remove values at runtime. static const array of pairs and switch/case can't be changed at runtime.

> Any suggestions?

You should probably use macros to initialize your array. Practical example (using switch/case):

```
const char* glErrorString(GLuint error){
    switch (error){
#define BRANCH(p) case(p): return #p; 
    BRANCH(GL_NO_ERROR)
    BRANCH(GL_INVALID_ENUM)
    BRANCH(GL_INVALID_VALUE)
    BRANCH(GL_INVALID_OPERATION)
    BRANCH(GL_STACK_OVERFLOW)
    BRANCH(GL_STACK_UNDERFLOW)
    BRANCH(GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY)
    BRANCH(GL_TABLE_TOO_LARGE   )
    default:
        return "Unknown error\n";
#undef  BRANCH
    };
}
```