# Iterable enum class in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, enum

For a small project I'm working on, I've been looking for an iterable `enum`-like class in C++, since neither C-style nor scoped `enum`s seem to support iteration in a way that isn't hack-y. I stumbled across [this (relatively) old article](http://www.drdobbs.com/when-enum-just-isnt-enough-enumeration-c/184403955), from which I've drawn inspiration to create a robust `Enum` class supporting iteration and C++11 features.

The client simply creates a `DEnum` class, which includes the desired `enum` items as static const members, inheriting from this `Enum` class. This prevents code using `DEnum` from creating new items. Local object copies of the `enum` items can be created through the default copy and copy-assignment ctors. I've also added a function that allows creation of a local subset of the `enum` items, which also supports iteration (including using range-for syntax). The class should be type-safe in preventing type conversion of its members and instantiated copies.

I'm just looking for any tips on how I could implement this better. Does this code follow C++11 best practices? Are there any problems I've overlooked?

```
// enum.h
#ifndef ENUM_H_
#define ENUM_H_

#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

template <class T>
class Enum {
 private:
  // Comparator used to determine enum item ordering
  struct EnumLTComparator {
    bool operator() (const T* e1, const T* e2) {
      return e1->value() < e2->value();
    }
  };

 public:
  typedef std::set<const T*, EnumLTComparator> ItemsSet;
  typedef typename ItemsSet::size_type set_size_type;
  typedef typename ItemsSet::const_iterator const_iterator;
  typedef typename ItemsSet::const_reverse_iterator const_r_iterator;

  int value() const { return value_; }
  static set_size_type size() { return items_.size(); }

  // Iteration
  static const_iterator begin() { return items_.cbegin(); }
  static const_iterator end() { return items_.cend(); }
  static const_r_iterator rbegin() { return items_.crbegin(); }
  static const_r_iterator rend() { return items_.crend(); }

  bool operator== (T e2) const {return this->value() == e2.value();}

  // Return a set which contains pointers to any number of unique enum items
  static ItemsSet Subset(std::initializer_list<T> items) {
    ItemsSet subset;
    for (auto i: items) {
      subset.insert(CorrespondingEnum(i.value()));
    }
    return subset;
  }

 protected:
  // Constructors
  explicit Enum(int value): value_(value) {
    // Warn clients if they try to add multiple items with the same value
    if (IsValidValue(value)) {
      std::cerr << "The value \'" << value << "\' has been assigned to "
                << "multiple items in this enum. All duplicates are omitted "
                << "from the set." << std::endl;
      return;
    }

    // This cast seems ugly, since the object being constructed by the
    //   inheriting class will already be of type T, but I don't see any
    //   way around this.
    items_.insert(static_cast<T*>(this));
  }
  // Compiler-generated copy and copy-assign ctors generate local copies of
  //   the static enum items

 private:
  static const T* CorrespondingEnum(int value) {
    auto EnumPredicateCorresponds = [value](const T* elem) -> bool {
      return elem->value() == value;
    };

    const_iterator it = find_if(items_.begin(),
                                items_.end(),
                                EnumPredicateCorresponds);

    return (it != items_.end()) ? *it : nullptr;
  }
  static bool IsValidValue(int value) {
    return CorrespondingEnum(value) != nullptr;
  }

  int value_;
  static ItemsSet items_;
};


#endif
```

And a client would use this class as follows:

```
// color.h
#ifndef COLOR_H_
#define COLOR_H_

#include "enum.h"

class Color: public Enum<Color> {
 public:
  using Enum::Enum; //Color::Color(int) is still protected

  static const Color blue;
  static const Color green;
  static const Color red;
  static const Color white;
  static const Color yellow;
  static const Color multicolor;
  static const Color hidden;
};

#endif
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
// color.cc
#include "color.h"
#include "enum.h"

// I would prefer not to require this, but I don't see a way around it
template<>
typename Enum<Color>::ItemsSet Enum<Color>::items_{};

const Color Color::blue(0);
const Color Color::green(1);
const Color Color::red(2);
const Color Color::white(3);
const Color Color::yellow(4);
const Color Color::multicolor(5);
const Color Color::hidden(6);
```

Finally, some testing with cout:

```
#include <iostream>

#include "color.h"

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main() {
  cout << Color::size() << endl; //7

  for (auto iCol = Color::begin(); iCol != Color::end(); ++iCol) {
    cout << (*iCol)->value() << endl;
  }
  /* 0
   * 1
   * 2
   * 3
   * 4
   * 5
   * 7
   */

  cout << (**(Color::begin()) == Color::blue) << endl;    //1
  cout << (**(Color::begin()) == Color::red) << endl;     //0
  cout << (**(Color::rbegin()) == Color::hidden) << endl; //1
  cout << (**(Color::rbegin()) == Color::yellow) << endl; //0

  auto subset = Color::Subset({Color::blue, Color::red});
  cout << (**(subset.begin()) == Color::blue) << endl; //1
  cout << (**(subset.rbegin()) == Color::red) << endl; //0
  for (auto iCol: subset) {
    cout << iCol->value() << endl;
    // 0
    // 2
  }

  //Color mauve(2); //Error: Color::Color is protected
  //Color *col = &(Color::red); //Error: can't convert from 'const Color*'
                                //  to Color*'
}
```

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/14309/conversion-between-enum-and-string-in-c-class-header?rq=1

Answer (score 6):

You are no longer using the enum properties.

```
const Color Color::blue(0);
const Color Color::green(1);
const Color Color::red(2);
const Color Color::white(3);
const Color Color::yellow(4);
const Color Color::multicolor(5);
const Color Color::hidden(6);
```

But rather a set of const values that have been put in a set. Sort of defeats the purpose of enum in my mind.

I would just create a class for iterating across enums.

#### This is what I would have done.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

template<typename T, T... args>
struct EnumIter : public std::iterator<std::input_iterator_tag, T,ptrdiff_t,const T*,const T&>
{
    static constexpr T              values[] = {args...};
    static constexpr std::size_t    size     = sizeof...(args);

    int     pos;
    EnumIter()   // No value is end
        : pos(size)
    {}
    EnumIter(T val)
        : pos(std::distance(&values[0], std::find(&values[0], &values[size], val)))
    {}

    const T&    operator*()                 const   {return values[pos];}
    EnumIter&   operator++()                        {++pos;return *this;}
    EnumIter    operator++(int)                     {EnumIter r(*this);this->operator++();return r;}
    bool        operator==(EnumIter const& rhs)     {return pos == rhs.pos;}
    bool        operator!=(EnumIter const& rhs)     {return pos != rhs.pos;}
};
template<typename T, T... args>
constexpr T EnumIter<T, args...>::values[];
```

Usage:

```
enum Ace { One = 101, Two = 233, Three = 455};
typedef struct EnumIter<Ace, One, Two, Three>  AceIter;

int main()
{
    for(AceIter loop(One); loop != AceIter(); ++loop)
    {
        std::cout << static_cast<int>(*loop) << "\n";
    }
}
```

Run

```
> g++ -std=c++11 enum.cpp
> ./a.out
101
233
455
```

Combine this with a previous printing of enum done here
[Conversion between enum and string in C++ class header](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/14309/conversion-between-enum-and-string-in-c-class-header?rq=1)

Comment: Shouldn't `Ace` be a strongly-typed `enum`?  It seems a little ugly to have casting done in the main loop.

Comment: @Jamal: casting is a different problem. And solved here: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/14309/conversion-between-enum-and-string-in-c-class-header?rq=1

Comment: Have not practiced `strongly-typed` enum's yet. So I don't know.

Comment: Okay.  I don't quite know if they'll clear that up by themselves (I've mostly noticed the existence of the old `enum`s), but I do know that the new ones aren't forced to become `int`s.

Comment: Can you expand on how this "defeats the purpose of enums in [your] mind"? The end result is a strong type which can take on a finite number of symbolic values, which seems to me like what `enum`s accomplish.

Comment: You can indeed have a `Color` object, as the compiler-generated copy and assignment ctors will provide you with one. All it shares with the "allowed values" (the `static const` members) is its type and the value for the `value_` member, but that is all that is needed to compare equality due to my definition of the `operator==` function. I recently fixed a mistake in the code - to change `value_` to non-`const` - which allows the ctors to work properly, so maybe this is where the confusion lies. You can change the color on the fly now with:
    `Color color = Color::red; color = Color::blue;`

Comment: Since you fixed that bug removed the comments.

Comment: Still defeats the purpose of `enum`. So rather then declare the compiler defined set of enum. You now have to build a class declare a set of static objects for every value in your class; then define every object (in a separate compilation unit). So you have not gained anything over the built in enum added a whole bunch of work for the developer to use it. This seems like a very Java like solution.

Comment: You built the `Enum` class so you could iterate over the enums. This is just a set with a default set of all values. If you want that just use a std::set of `enum` you get the same result but with no extra code and very little work. Seems you are trying to solve a non existent problem. Easier to concentrate on building specialized iterators.

Comment: What do you mean you "have not gained anything over the built-in `enum`"? Classic `enum` has implicit conversion to `int`, and neither it, nor scoped `enum` (`enum class`) supports iteration in a robust way. The code you've suggested does not provide me with a strongly-typed enumeration.

Comment: @Libster: As it stands this class does not buy me anything. It basically causes me more work without solving any real problems that I am having with enumerators. The description of the `Iterable enum` is easy to solve with the much simpler example I provide (which imposes no work on the user).

Comment: @Libster: You seem to be misunderstanding how this sites work. You put code here and ask for other people opinion so that you can improve your code. If you don't agree with my opinion you don't need to use it. In that case keep your code the way it is. But in my opinion it is not going to be very useful to anybody else as it stands.

Comment: But your example does not fulfill my requirement of strong typing. It's perfectly fine for you not to have a personal use for my code, but dismissing it and then not providing a counter-example fulfilling the same basic criteria does not seem very productive.

Comment: @Libster: Strong typing is a criteria! It just seems like the goal was an iterator-able enum. Why do people need a strong Enum. My job is to point out what I think is wrong with the code. You provide a library, but it is not standalone requiring a lot of user work to make it usable. Thus it seems like a lot of work. And the benefit is questionable. It may seem counterproductive to you because you are emotionally invested in some code I don't like. But the comments are useful to others.

Comment: Does this meaningful? You already know what element have in this enum when you define your iter. Each time you modify the enum, you have to modify the iter.