# Array-like container for uints shorter than 8 bits

Tags: c++, array, bitwise, iterator, container

**Follow-up:** [Array-like container for uints shorter than 8 bits (Rev 1)](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/63066/array-like-container-for-uints-shorter-than-8-bits-rev-1)

---

First of all: yes, I need this kind of array to generate data for a piece of hardware, and it must be stored and manipulated somewhere. The general consensus regarding bit manipulation seems to be "if you need to do that, there's something wrong".

The array-like container (`PackedBitfieldArray`) I'm writing is for `uintx_t`s, where `x` = \$2^n\$ (`x` is an integer power of two). No `uintx_t` crosses (or may cross) any word boundary of the actual underlying storage type. `PackedBitfieldArray` is templated with the number of `Bits` per element, number of `Elements` (just like `std::array`) and the default storage type `V` is `uint8_t`.

Elements are accessed by `proxy` and `const_proxy` objects, and I want to provide an `iterator` (already included below) and a `const_iterator` (not yet included because I want to avoid too much duplicate code), for use with algorithms.

Here's the header:

```
#ifndef SFDD_PACKEDBITFIELDARRAY_H
#define SFDD_PACKEDBITFIELDARRAY_H

#include <array>
#include <cstdint>

template<size_t Bits, size_t Elements, typename V = uint8_t>
class PackedBitfieldArray
{
  // array type for packable bitfields-kinda-types    
  public:
    typedef V value_type;

    static constexpr size_t value_bitwidth = 8*sizeof(value_type);
    static_assert(Bits < value_bitwidth, "Bit size mut be smaller than the underlying storage type's bit size");
    static_assert(value_bitwidth % Bits == 0, "Cannot pack this : (value_bitwidth % Bits per element) != 0");

    static constexpr value_type arg_mask = (1<< Bits)-1;
    static constexpr size_t value_size = (Bits*Elements+(value_bitwidth-1))/value_bitwidth; // number of underlying storage elements

    class proxy
    {
      public:
        proxy(value_type& data, size_t offset) : data_(data), offset_(offset) {}

        proxy& operator=(value_type value)
        {
          value_type orVal = ((value & arg_mask) << offset_);
          data_ = (data_ & ~(arg_mask << offset_)) | orVal;
          return *this;
        }

        operator value_type() const
        {
          return (data_ & (arg_mask << offset_)) >> offset_;
        }

      private:
        value_type& data_;
        size_t offset_;
    };

    class const_proxy
    {
      public:
        const_proxy(value_type& data, size_t offset) : data_(data), offset_(offset) {}

        operator value_type() const
        {
          return (data_ & (arg_mask << offset_)) >> offset_;
        }

      private:
        const value_type& data_;
        size_t offset_;
    };

    value_type* data() {return data_.data();}
    const value_type* data() const {return data_.data();}

    proxy operator[](size_t i)
    {
      size_t i_ = i*Bits/value_bitwidth;
      uint8_t offset = i * Bits % value_bitwidth;
      return proxy(data()[i_], offset);
    }

    class iterator : public std::iterator<std::forward_iterator_tag, proxy>
    {
      public:
        iterator(value_type* data, size_t i)
        {
          size_t i_ = i*Bits/value_bitwidth;
          offset_ = i * Bits % value_bitwidth;
          data_ = &data[i_];
        }

        proxy operator*() const {return proxy(*data_, offset_);}

        iterator& operator++()
        {
          offset_ += Bits;
          if (offset_ == value_bitwidth)
          {
            offset_ = 0;
            data_++;
          }
          return *this;
        }

        bool operator==(const iterator& rhs)
        {
          return ((data_ == rhs.data_) && (offset_ == rhs.offset_));
        }

        bool operator!=(const iterator& rhs) {return !(operator==(rhs));}
      private:
        value_type* data_;
        size_t offset_;

    };

    iterator begin()
    {
      return iterator(data_.data(), 0);
    }

    iterator end()
    {
      return iterator(&data_.data()[value_size], 0); // WRONG
    }

  private:
  std::array<value_type, value_size> data_;
};


#endif // SFDD_PACKEDBITFIELDARRAY_H
```

This is the first time I've written an iterator, and I basically just copied the implementation from [this CR answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/57699/37034). Please do not suggest to use boost, as the environment I'm writing this for pollutes boost's template parameter names with evil macros.

- Do the arguments for `iterator::iterator()` make sense? Should I go for an index instead?
- In cases where the upper bits of the last storage element are not used (e.g. with `Bits = 2`, `Elements = 3`, `V = uint8_t`), `PackedBitfieldArray::end()` is not initialized correctly - this might influence the answer to the previous question (iterator constructor arguments).
- Can I avoid duplicate code in `iterator::iterator()` and `PackedBitfieldArray::operator[]()`?
- I think a `forward_iterator` is sufficient in my case, are there any reasons to enhance it to `bidirectional` or `random_access` anyway?
  This is the first time I've written an iterator of any kind. Is something essential missing?
- Once I have a sufficiently well working iterator, how should I implement the const version from there without duplicating most of the code?

Usage examples:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <bitset>
#include <iostream>

#include "packedBitfieldArray.h"

int main()
{
  static const size_t bits = 2;
  static const size_t n = 8;
  typedef PackedBitfieldArray<bits, n, uint8_t> PackedBitfield;
  PackedBitfield a;

  using namespace std;

  cout << "bits = " << bits << ", n = " << n << ", [a] = " << sizeof(a) << "\n";
  cout << "a.arg_mask = 0b" << std::bitset<8*sizeof(PackedBitfield::value_type)>(a.arg_mask) << "\n\n";

  /* Fill with indices */
  for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
    a[i] = i;
  }

  cout << "\nfor loop, C-like element access:\n";
  for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
    cout << "a[" << i << "] = " << (int)a[i] << "\n";
  }

  cout << "\nfor loop with iterators:\n";
  for (auto it = a.begin(); it != a.end(); ++it)
  {
    cout << "a[...] = " << (int)*it << " (0b" << std::bitset<8*sizeof(PackedBitfield::value_type)>(*it) << ")\n";
  }

  cout << "\nfor_each with a lambda:\n";
  std::for_each(a.begin(), a.end(), [](const PackedBitfield::proxy pr) {cout << "a[...] = " << (int)pr << " (0b" << std::bitset<8*sizeof(PackedBitfield::value_type)>(pr) << ")\n";});

  cout << "\nunderlying data dump:\n";
  for (size_t i = 0; i < a.value_size; i++)
  {
    cout << "a[" << i << "_] = " << (int)a.data()[i] << " (0b" << std::bitset<8*sizeof(PackedBitfield::value_type)>(a.data()[i]) << ")\n";
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
bits = 2, n = 8, [a] = 2
a.arg_mask = 0b00000011


for loop, C-like element access:
a[0] = 0
a[1] = 1
a[2] = 2
a[3] = 3
a[4] = 0
a[5] = 1
a[6] = 2
a[7] = 3

for loop with iterators:
a[...] = 0 (0b00000000)
a[...] = 1 (0b00000001)
a[...] = 2 (0b00000010)
a[...] = 3 (0b00000011)
a[...] = 0 (0b00000000)
a[...] = 1 (0b00000001)
a[...] = 2 (0b00000010)
a[...] = 3 (0b00000011)

for_each with a lambda:
a[...] = 0 (0b00000000)
a[...] = 1 (0b00000001)
a[...] = 2 (0b00000010)
a[...] = 3 (0b00000011)
a[...] = 0 (0b00000000)
a[...] = 1 (0b00000001)
a[...] = 2 (0b00000010)
a[...] = 3 (0b00000011)

underlying data dump:
a[0_] = 228 (0b11100100)
a[1_] = 228 (0b11100100)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will patch your code:

```
iterator end()
{
  return iterator(data_.data(), Elements);
}
```

Now you can try e.g. this in your `main()`:

```
static const size_t bits = 2;
static const size_t n = 5;
```

Output:

```
bits = 2, n = 5, [a] = 2
a.arg_mask = 0b00000011


for loop, C-like element access:
a[0] = 0
a[1] = 1
a[2] = 2
a[3] = 3
a[4] = 0

for loop with iterators:
a[...] = 0 (0b00000000)
a[...] = 1 (0b00000001)
a[...] = 2 (0b00000010)
a[...] = 3 (0b00000011)
a[...] = 0 (0b00000000)

for_each with a lambda:
a[...] = 0 (0b00000000)
a[...] = 1 (0b00000001)
a[...] = 2 (0b00000010)
a[...] = 3 (0b00000011)
a[...] = 0 (0b00000000)

underlying data dump:
a[0_] = 228 (0b11100100)
a[1_] = 52 (0b00110100)
```

That should answer your first two questions: It is OK with this correction.
For the `iterator` you can use:

1. Template (with some SFINEA for iterator->const_iterator)
2. Inheritance (common base with the implementation)
3. Composition (common struct to place inside as a member) to share some code.

For `operator[]` I would not worry about duplication, but you can solve it by const_proxy->proxy **private** constructor (and `friend`) and some `const_cast` to help you. Not nice, I would rather copy three lines and adapt. Again, some templated private helper could solve that as well.

It is your class, if you are fine with `forward_iterator`, then it is fine. If not, enhance it and use [std category tag](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator).

Comment: The fix you suggested for the end iterator was plain and simple, I simply overlooked that. I'm having serious problems with the const vs non-const iterator template implementation. I've tried the route outlined in http://www.drdobbs.com/the-standard-librarian-defining-iterato/184401331?pgno=1 with a bool template parameter for const-ness and `std::conditional` to define internal types. This might be a point for an upcoming revision, though.

Comment: I accepted this answer because it addressed all aspects I asked about, thank you! However, I think there's more to be done and I'll open a new question for the revised code (which has changed a lot).