# Array-like container for uints shorter than 8 bits (Rev 1)

Tags: c++, array, bitwise, iterator, container

This is a follow-up to [Array-like container for uints shorter than 8 bits](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/62946/array-like-container-for-uints-shorter-than-8-bits)

In short: The `PackedBitfieldArray` should be a kind of container for packed (unsigned) ints shorter than 8 bits. It provides proxy objects for manipulation and iterators.

What I have changed:

- `PackedBitfieldArray::end()` now returns a correct past-the-end iterator (that was broken in the previous version). There also `const` versions of `begin()` and `end()`.
- `PackedBitfieldArray::operator[]()` now has a `const` companion.
- The proxy objects `proxy` and `const_proxy` are now derived from a `proxyT` template that implements the `const` version. The non-const version adds an assignment operator.
- The iterators are now `random_access_iterator` (before: `forward_iterator`, I've added the necessary decrement and offset (is that their name?) operators.
- The iterators are now derived from a common template to minimize duplicate code (there is none, I think).
- The iterators now store an index where they stored an offset before. This might speed up everything related to random access, but slow down `++`, `--` and repeated access to the same location.

Here's the code, questions and things I'd like to know better are below that.

## Header:

```
#ifndef SFDD_PACKEDBITFIELDARRAY_H
#define SFDD_PACKEDBITFIELDARRAY_H

#include <array>
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iterator>

template<size_t Bits, size_t Elements, typename V = uint8_t>
class PackedBitfieldArray
{
  public:
    typedef V value_type;

    static constexpr size_t value_bitwidth = 8*sizeof(value_type);
    static_assert(Bits <= value_bitwidth, "Bit size must not be greater than the underlying storage type's bit size");
    static_assert(value_bitwidth % Bits == 0, "Cannot pack this : (value_bitwidth % Bits per element) != 0");

    static constexpr value_type arg_mask = (1<< Bits)-1;
    // number of underlying storage elements
    static constexpr size_t value_size = (Bits*Elements+(value_bitwidth-1))/value_bitwidth;


  private:
    template<bool isConst>
    class proxyT
    {
      public:
        typedef typename std::conditional<isConst,
                                          const PackedBitfieldArray::value_type,
                                          PackedBitfieldArray::value_type>::type value_type;

        operator PackedBitfieldArray::value_type() const
        {
          return (data_ & (arg_mask << offset_)) >> offset_;
        }

      protected:
        proxyT(value_type& data, size_t offset) : data_(data), offset_(offset) {}
        value_type& data_;
        size_t offset_;
    };


  public:
    class proxy : public proxyT<false>
    {
      public:
        proxy(value_type& data, size_t offset) : proxyT<false>(data, offset) {}

        proxy& operator=(value_type value)
        {
          value_type orVal = ((value & arg_mask) << this->offset_);
          this->data_ = (this->data_ & ~(arg_mask << this->offset_)) | orVal;
          return *this;
        }

    };



    class const_proxy : public proxyT<true> {};

    value_type* data() {return data_.data();}
    const value_type* data() const {return data_.data();}
    void clear() {data_.fill(0);}

    proxy operator[](size_t i)
    {
      size_t i_ = i*Bits/value_bitwidth;
      uint8_t offset = i * Bits % value_bitwidth;
      return proxy(data()[i_], offset);
    }

    const_proxy operator[](size_t i) const
    {
      size_t i_ = i*Bits/value_bitwidth;
      uint8_t offset = i * Bits % value_bitwidth;
      return const_proxy(data()[i_], offset);
    }



    template<bool isConst>
    class iteratorT
    {
      public:
        typedef std::random_access_iterator_tag iterator_category;
        typedef typename std::conditional<isConst, const_proxy, proxy>::type value_type;
        typedef typename std::conditional<isConst, const PackedBitfieldArray::value_type, PackedBitfieldArray::value_type>::type storage_type;
        typedef value_type& reference;
        typedef value_type* pointer;
        typedef ptrdiff_t difference_type;

        /** Constructor **/
        iteratorT(storage_type* data, size_t i) : data_(data), i_(i) { }



        /**
          Input iterator, Forward Iterator
        **/
        iteratorT& operator++()// prefix increment
        {
          i_++;
          return *this;
        }

        iteratorT operator++(int)// postfix increment
        {
          iteratorT previous(*this);
          operator++();
          return previous;
        }

        bool operator==(const iteratorT& rhs) const
        {
          return ((data_ == rhs.data_) && (i_ == rhs.i_));
        }

        bool operator!=(const iteratorT& rhs) const {return !(operator==(rhs));}

        proxy operator*() const
        {
          size_t dataIndex = i_*Bits/value_bitwidth;
          uint8_t offset = i_ * Bits % value_bitwidth;
          return proxy(data_[dataIndex], offset);
        }



        /**
          Bidirectional iterator
        **/
        iteratorT& operator--()
        {
          i_--;
        }

        iteratorT operator--(int)
        {
          iteratorT previous(*this);
          operator--();
          return previous;
        }



        /**
          Random Access Iterator
        **/
        iteratorT& operator+=(size_t n)
        {
          i_ += n;
          return *this;
        }

        iteratorT operator+(size_t n) const
        {
          iteratorT result(*this);
          result+= n;
          return result;
        }

        iteratorT& operator-=(size_t n)
        {
          i_ -= n;
          return *this;
        }

        iteratorT operator-(size_t n) const
        {
          iteratorT result(*this);
          result-= n;
          return result;
        }



        /**
          Difference (do I need further comparisons?)
        **/
        typename iteratorT::difference_type operator-(const iteratorT& rhs) const
        {
          return i_ - rhs.i_;
        }

      private:
        storage_type* data_;
        size_t i_;
    };

    typedef iteratorT<false> iterator;
    typedef iteratorT<true> const_iterator;
    iterator begin()
    {
      return iterator(data_.data(), 0);
    }

    iterator end()
    {
      return iterator(data_.data(), Elements);
    }

    const_iterator begin() const
    {
      return const_iterator(data(), 0);
    }

    const_iterator end() const
    {
      return const_iterator(data_.data(), Elements);
    }

  private:
  std::array<value_type, value_size> data_;
};


#endif // SFDD_PACKEDBITFIELDARRAY_H
```

## Usage Example

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <bitset>
#include <iostream>

#include "packedBitfieldArray.h"

int main()
{
  static const size_t bits = 2;
  static const size_t n = 9;
  typedef PackedBitfieldArray<bits, n, uint8_t> PackedBitfield;
  PackedBitfield a;

  using namespace std;

  cout << "bits = " << bits << ", n = " << n << ", [a] = " << sizeof(a) << "\n";
  cout << "a.arg_mask = 0b" << std::bitset<8*sizeof(PackedBitfield::value_type)>(a.arg_mask) << "\n\n";

  a.clear();

  /* Fill with indices */
  for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
    a[i] = i;
  }

  cout << "\nfor loop, C-like element access:\n";
  for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
    cout << "a[" << i << "] = " << (int)a[i] << "\n";
  }

  cout << "\nfor loop with iterators:\n";
  for (auto it = a.begin(); it != a.end(); ++it)
  {
    cout << "a[...] = " << *it;//(int)(uint8_t)*it;
    cout << " (0b" << std::bitset<8*sizeof(PackedBitfield::value_type)>(*it) << ")\n";
  }

  cout << "\nfor_each with a lambda:\n";
  std::for_each(a.begin(), a.end(), [](const PackedBitfield::proxy pr) {cout << "a[...] = " << (int)pr << " (0b" << std::bitset<8*sizeof(PackedBitfield::value_type)>(pr) << ")\n";});

  cout << "\nunderlying data dump:\n";
  for (size_t i = 0; i < a.value_size; i++)
  {
    cout << "a[" << i << "_] = " << (int)a.data()[i] << " (0b" << std::bitset<8*sizeof(PackedBitfield::value_type)>(a.data()[i]) << ")\n";
  }

  cout << "\nfor loop, random access offset:\n";
  for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
    auto it = a.begin() + i;
    cout << "a[" << i << "] = " << (int)*it << "\n";
  }

  size_t start = 2;
  cout << "\nfor loop, random access offset from " << start << ":\n";
  auto iStart = a.begin() + start;
  for (size_t i = start; i < n; i++)
  {
    auto it = iStart + (i - start);
    cout << "a[" << i << "] = " << (int)*it << "\n";
  }

  const PackedBitfield b = a;
  auto icStart = b.begin();

  return 0;
}
```

## Questions and Problems

### Source

- Are the comments ok (amount, type, and quality)?
- Is the formatting ok?

### `PackedBitfieldArray`

- I have defined a `value_type` which is the underlying storage type, see `PackedBitfieldArray::data_`, which is a `std::array`). Should I add a second typedef for read/write access using proxies? This would add some flexibility, but make it harder to understand/use. The names would then be `storage_type` and `value_type`.

### `proxyT`

- this class is private to `PackedBitfieldArray` and has a protected constructor. It can only be constructed by `proxy` and `const_proxy`, which derive from it.
- I don't know how well the `operator value_type()` behaves when other int-like types must be assigned the proxy's value. When I run into problems with that, should I add a template conversion operator that handles integers or would that create even more problems?
- I will most probably have statements like `bool b = somePackedBitfieldArray[i]`. Implicit conversion to bool is said (! I have no real experience with that) to be dangerous. What should I prepare for regarding implicit conversions to bool?

### `const_proxy`

- derived from `proxyT`, but doesn't refine anything. A `typedef proxyT<true> const_proxy` wouldn't work here, because it couldn't be constructed: the base constructor is protected. Is that particularly bad?

### `proxy`

- Similar to the `proxyT` conversion operator, will I run into problems with the assignment operator here?

### `iteratorT`

- The internal types seem to work, but I can't see any sense for `reference` and `pointer` types, because the interface uses the proxy objects. However, containers should allow references and pointers to the objects they store, right?
- is `proxy`/`const_proxy` the correct `value_type` in the first place?
- Do I need more comparison operators, such as `<`, `>`, `<=`, `>=`?

### Testing

- How do I test this (the container, the iterators) without too much trial and error?

Answer (score 4):

I would like to see some extra comments or some brief description before the `proxy` and `proxyT` member types. Their implementations are not trivial either, involving some unclear bit-shifts. So I think some explanation of what their methods do is proper.

A brief header description of what the `PackedBitfieldArray` does, what are its most remarkable features, etc, is also nice. Place such comment just before the class declaration. It should be brief but summarise the purposes of the class. Adding a short usage example in the comment is also valid.

The only comment I currently find useless is this one:

```
/** Constructor **/
iteratorT(storage_type* data, size_t i) : data_(data), i_(i) { }
```

---

If you want to be more pedantic, you can use `std::size_t`/`std::uint8_t`. Personally, I'm fine with just `size_t`/`uint8_t` though.

---

Currently, you have interface and implementation together in the header file. For inline classes and template classes, I usually separate the code in two files.

In the header file (`.h/.hpp`) I keep just the class declaration, as if it were a normal class. This makes easier for someone who is just looking for the name or signature of a method and does not wish to be bothered by the implementation details.

The template implementation is place inside an `.inl` (inline) file. This extension is recognised by most IDEs and text editors. Then the `.inl` is included at the end of the header. It looks something like this:

**Class.hpp**:

```
// include guards...

template<class T> class Class {
public:
    void methodA();
    void methodB();
};

#include "Class.inl"
```

**Class.inl**:

```
template<class T>
void Class<T>::methodA()
{
    // implementation ...
}

template<class T>
void Class<T>::methodB()
{
    // implementation ...
}

...
```

Comment: I've never separated declaration and definition for template classes, but that might indeed increase readability. However, as I started to add doxygen-ready comments for the `proxy` classes, things escalated. I'll need to find a good balance here.

Answer (score 2):

### Typedefs on the container

```
typedef proxy reference             // this one is fine
typedef const_proxy const_reference // this is problematic
```

or you can rename them completely. Look at [`std::bitset::reference`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/reference) or [`std::vector<bool>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool) for some inspiration, but the `const_reference = bool` there in `vector<bool>` is considered unlucky choice (violates the common rules about containers). The problem is, that `const_reference` can be used for both return type (where it should be real reference) and as argument (where it should be `value_type` in this case).

### proxyT

I was at first worried if the code can even compile, having public base class which is private to the container, but it seems to work. Conversion `operator value_type()` should be fine and you can specialize it (or use SFINAE) if you wish to use `bool` for `Bits=1`:

```
typedef V storage_type
typedef conditional_t<Bits==1,bool,V> value_type
```

Note that I have just used C++14 [`conditional_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional) which is defined as

```
template< bool B, class T, class F >
using conditional_t = typename conditional<B,T,F>::type;
```

You can bring it to your C++11 code as well (and I am using it this way) and make your code a bit nicer and more readable.

### const_proxy

Well, you could possibly use other SFINAE trics to allow simple `typedef proxyT<false> reference; typedef proxyT<true> const_reference`, but I would not worry that much here.

### iteratorT

I think that `value_type` and `reference` should be the same as on the container here. Pointer could in fact be the iterator itself, but I would rather not define it. I hope somebody more experienced will address this, because this is getting opinion-based and touches the problems about [`vector<bool>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool) - `vector<bool>::iterator` is derived from [`std::iterator<std::random_access_iterator_tag, bool>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator).

---

Comments about this topic (`vector<bool>::const_reference` and such) appriciated, I will gladly edit the answer, if somebody can shed some more light at it.

Comment: regarding `proxyT`: It took me a second look to understand your point, but it makes sense now. I thought you were suggesting to use `bool` as storage type, which would remove the packed-ness from my container, but using it as a `value_type` for bool proxies seems to be a better fit for `operator value_type()` and `operator=()` in that case.

Comment: It should have been obvious from your own context: *Should I add a second typedef for read/write access using proxies? ... The names would then be `storage_type` and `value_type`.* I have seconded the idea and defined `value_type=bool` for `Bits=1` and `value_type=storage_type=V` for `Bits>1`.

Comment: I see, thanks for the clarification. I didn't have that perspective.